# Cannot convert dateTime string with Datetime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime

This is the exact string i have: 18-2-2014 00:00:00

My code bumps into this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

At this line:

```
newDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
                        part[0],
                        "dd-mm-jjjj hh:mm:ss", 
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                        ); //I tried a couple of time string variations, but it should be the above or "dd-m-jjjj hh:mm:ss".
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: ffs! did i really put jjjj there.... damn excel. That is dutch licensed excel :/.

Comment: if you look at [DateTime String Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), there's no `jjjj`

Comment: Yeah, how did i read over that a billion times... Probably because i used that string format for the whole day in the dutch excel version on my work. dd is the same here, mm is the same here except for yyyy, it's jjjj here...

Comment: Don't worry, in Danish it is `åååå` for "year".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mm` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#mmSpecifier) is for minutes. Use [`M` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#M_Specifier) which is for months (`1` to `12`).

[`hh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) format is for `01` to `12` (*12-hour clock*). It doesn't have `00` as an hour. That's why you should use [`HH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier) format which is for `00` to `23` (*24-hour clock*).

And there is no `jjjj` date and time format specifier which I think you want to use [`yyyy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#yyyySpecifier) format.

```
var s = "18-2-2014 00:00:00";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s,
                              "dd-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
2/18/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/Sg3onR)</kbd>.

For more information, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**NOTE**: As Jeppe Stig Nielsen [*pointed*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016751/cannot-convert-datetime-string-with-datetime-parseexact#comment33374137_22017101), since we don't know your culture exactly (can be `nl-BE` or `nl-NL`) your [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) day for is `d` not `dd`.

That's why you might need to use `d` format instead `dd`.

Comment: Also the hour `00` is not valid on a 12-hour system (must be between `01` and `12`) which is why you changed `hh` into `HH` (from `00` through `23`).

Comment: We can't tell from his input (it is not one of the first nine days in the month), but I am sure `"d-M-yyyy"` is more like what he wants than `"dd-M-yyyy"`. Cf. `(new CultureInfo("nl-NL")).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very detailed explanation. My culture is nl-NL could you go a bit in depth on that? Like the comment from @JeppeStigNielsen?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You have a good point. It could be `nl-BE` or `nl-NL` but both's [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has `d` format instead of `dd`. Also added to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
newDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(part[0],"dd-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I suspect the OP *really* wants HH rather than hh.